# How to make a checkbox? if (checkbox) set to enable filter by field

Tags: php, html, database, checkbox, filter

How to make sure that if (checkbox) is set, then enable the filter by sport_id field and only those lines are displayed where in the sport_id field there is '1'. Oracle Database

```
<form action=" " method="post">
  <input type="checkbox" name="sport_id" value="1">
</form>

<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
 <p></p>
 <div class="checkbox">
   <label>
     <?php echo form_checkbox('sport_id', sport::checkboxValid(), 
        ($this->input->get('sport_id') > 0) ? 'checked="checked"' : '')?>
   </label>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Either I am missing something from your question or you need to:
1. use that PHP part inside `<input ...` or
2. use JavaScript to update on some change.

Comment: can you give more details? I'm just trying to do this for the first time

Comment: `<div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <input type="radio" value="contact" name="type" {{ old('type', $menu->type) === 'contact' ? 'checked' : '' }}> Contact
        </label>
    </div>
</div>` Check in similar framework like yours: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/getting-a-checkbox-checked

Answer (score 0):

You can use in the `if()` condition

```
isset($_POST['sport_id'])
```

Comment: can you give more details?
I'm just trying to do this for the first time